# Bootbox.js dialog is being cutted

Tags: javascript, bootbox

Im using Bootbox.js for confirm dialog. But the dialog is showing on the left of the screen( 50% of it is cutted) How to set that every bootbox dialog will be showing on the middle of the screen?

Comment: More details are required to diagnose this problem. Is it related to a specific browser? Did you modify the source code for Bootbox, and break something? Maybe you made CSS changes that absolutely position the Bootbox off the side of the screen? There are a lot of possibilities. This question is likely too broad to answer without more details.

Answer (score 0):

- Use the correct version of bootboxjs for each bootstrap version:

Bootbox 4.0.0 is the first release to support Bootstrap 3.0.0.

Bootbox 3.3.0 is the last release to support Bootstrap 2.2.x.

- Verify yours css and js are fully loaded:

Use http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/ and http://bootboxjs.com/

And try a basic bootbox dialog.